# How to make insensitive value type for include?

Tags: javascript

There is a code:

```
let exceptLayers: (string | number)[] = [1,2];
let n = "1";

let v = exceptLayers.includes(n);
console.log(v);
```

It returns `false` How to make insensitive value by string and number

Comment: `exceptLayer.includes(+n)`. Convert n to number.

Comment: You're comparing a string with an array of numbers.

Comment: Is the actual type of `exceptLayers` `(string | number)[]` (i.e. it will contain *both* strings and numbers) or did you just add that annotation to make TypeScript stop complaining about `exceptLayers.includes(n)` and it’ll always be numbers?

Comment: I need to comapre this in both cases in string and number. Because I get looking number from user, he can enter this as number or string

Comment: So you can have `exceptLayers = [1, "2", 3, 4, "5"]`? Also, how does the user influence the *type* of value you get? Note: a string that contains only digits is still a string, not a number.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: User can enter "1" or 1 and array can be [1] or ["1"]

Comment: You can't make it insensitive as written. `includes` uses `Object.is` under the hood, which essentially does a `===` comparison between the two values. As `"1" ===1` is false, there needs to be a modification somewhere else in order either make "1" into 1 or 1 into "1" for that to be true, *or*, there needs to be a different comparison used other than `includes`.

Comment: Maybe to use `.find`?

Comment: Are you always going to look for a string in the array, or will it sometimes be a number too? Is `"001"` in `[1, 2]`? Is `1` in `["001", 2]`?

Comment: You could use find, and then use `==` in there which will implicitly coerce thus allowing "1" == 1

Comment: Users can't enter numbers -- input values are always strings.